# Error running Python script - ImportError: No module named onepv1lib.onep

Tags: python

I recently created a script that exports data from Exosite into a CSV file.

The script ran perfectly for a few months until recently when I started to get the error:

```
File "archive_data_multiple_REC.py", line 16, in <module> from onepv1lib.onep import OnepV1
ImportError: No module named onepv1lib.onep
```

Line 16 in my script is:

```
from onepv1lib.onep import OnepV1
```

Comment: What has changed in the script's evironment? Was the `onepv1lib` module moved or removed? Where is it located relative to your script. Has the Python path changed?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, nothing at all has changed with regards to the environment. I had set up my computer to run this script everyday, which it did fine up until a few days ago. I didn't move or remove onepv1lib not has the Python path changed. I only noticed the issue when I realised data was no longer being exported so ran the script manually, which is when it displayed the message above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your code doesn't migrated from `0.3` version of `pyopen` to `0.7.4`.
Package name were updated from `onepv1lib` to `pyopen` starting from version `0.7.4`. So update line

```
from onepv1lib.onep import OnepV1
```

to

```
from pyopen.onep import OnepV1
```

Also update other import statements to avoid same error within your codebase.

Comment: I gave this a try but I got a similar message ImportError: No module named pyopen.onep

Comment: install it with `pip install pyopen`

Comment: I tried pip install pyonep (instead of pyopen). This resolved issue. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to run in console `pip install onepv1lib`

Comment: I gave this a try and got the message "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement onepv1lib".